# Matrix ends up as negative values near zero, just can't figure out why

Tags: loops, matlab, matrix, rounding

The code that I am working on for finding the radiosities of each of the different walls in an enclosed system is listed below. Using Matlab 2023b, I've been running into difficulties with the end J matrix being all negative values close to zero, shown below the code. Given that this isn't actually possible in the real world, as all of the temperatures would be below 0 Kelvin, I know that I am going wrong, but can't figure out where. The code for the view factors and areas, while messy, should be accurate to the case.

Any help is appreciated, as I am stumped in finding the issue!

```
clear
clc

%%Setting up givens
Boltz = 5.67e-8;
%Top
Dimensions(1,1) = 0;
Dimensions(1,2) = 10;
Dimensions(1,3) = 20;
T(1) = 0;
E(1) = 0;
%Front
Dimensions(2,1) = 0;
Dimensions(2,2) = 5;
Dimensions(2,3) = 20;
T(2) = 0;
%Back
Dimensions(3,1) = 2;
Dimensions(3,2) = 5;
Dimensions(3,3) = 20;
T(3) = 673;
E(3) = 0.4;
%Floor
Dimensions(4,1) = 1;
Dimensions(4,2) = 10;
Dimensions(4,3) = 20;
T(4) = 473;
E(4) = 1;
%End 1
Dimensions(5,1) = 0;
Dimensions(5,2) = 5;
Dimensions(5,3) = 10;
T(5) = 0;
%End 2
Dimensions(6,1) = 0;
Dimensions(6,2) = 5;
Dimensions(6,3) = 10;
T(6) = 0;
%Calculating Areas
for i = 1:6
    Dimensions(i,4) = Dimensions(i,2) * Dimensions(i,3);
end
%Surface Areas
A1 = Dimensions(4,4); %Floor
A2 = Dimensions(3,4); %Back
A3 = Dimensions(5,4) + Dimensions(6,4); %Ends
A4 = Dimensions(1,4) + Dimensions(2,4); %Front and Top
%% Finding View Factors Fij
for i = 1:6
    for j = 1:6
        if i == 1
            if j == 2 || j == 3
                F(i,j) = 0.1669;
            end
            if j == 4 
                F(i,j) = 0.5090;
            end            
            if j == 5 || j == 6
                F(i,j) = 0.0787;                
            end
        end
        if i == 2
            if j == 3
                F(i,j) = 0.1653;
            end
            if j == 4
                F(i,j) = F(2,1);
            end
            if j == 5 || j == 6
                F(i,j) = 0.0837;
            end
        end
        if i == 3
            if j == 4
                F(i,j) = F(2,4);
            end
            if j == 5 || j == 6
                F(i,j) = F(2,j);
            end
        end
        if i == 4
            if j == 5 || j == 6
                F(i,j) = 0.0787;
            end
        end
        if i == 5
            if j == 6
                F(i,j) = 0.0362;
            end
        end
        F(i,i) = 0;
        F(j,i) = Dimensions(i,4)/Dimensions(j,4)*F(i,j);
    end
end

for i = 1:6
    Fsum(i) = sum(F(i,:));
end

AreaF(1,1) = F(4,4);
AreaF(1,2) = F(4,3);
AreaF(1,3) = F(4,5) + F(4,6);
AreaF(1,4) = F(4,1) + F(4,2);
AreaF(2,1) = F(3,4);
AreaF(2,2) = F(3,3);
AreaF(2,3) = F(3,5) + F(3,6);
AreaF(2,4) = F(3,1) + F(3,2);
AreaF(3,1) = (Dimensions(5,4)*F(5,4)+Dimensions(6,4)*F(6,4))/(Dimensions(5,4)+Dimensions(6,4));
AreaF(3,2) = (Dimensions(5,4)*F(5,3)+Dimensions(6,4)*F(6,3))/(Dimensions(5,4)+Dimensions(6,4));
AreaF(3,3) = (Dimensions(6,4)*F(6,5))/(Dimensions(5,4)+Dimensions(6,4)) + (Dimensions(5,4)*F(5,6))/(Dimensions(5,4)+Dimensions(6,4));
AreaF(3,4) = (Dimensions(5,4)*F(5,1)+Dimensions(6,4)*F(6,1))/(Dimensions(5,4)+Dimensions(6,4)) + (Dimensions(5,4)*F(5,2)+Dimensions(6,4)*F(6,2))/(Dimensions(5,4)+Dimensions(6,4));
AreaF(4,1) = (Dimensions(1,4)*F(1,4)+Dimensions(2,4)*F(2,4))/(Dimensions(1,4)+Dimensions(2,4));
AreaF(4,2) = (Dimensions(1,4)*F(1,3)+Dimensions(2,4)*F(2,3))/(Dimensions(1,4)+Dimensions(2,4));
AreaF(4,3) = (Dimensions(1,4)*F(1,5)+Dimensions(2,4)*F(2,5))/(Dimensions(1,4)+Dimensions(2,4)) + (Dimensions(1,4)*F(1,6)+Dimensions(2,4)*F(2,6))/(Dimensions(1,4)+Dimensions(2,4));
AreaF(4,4) = (Dimensions(2,4)*F(2,1))/(Dimensions(1,4)+Dimensions(2,4)) + (Dimensions(1,4)*F(1,2))/(Dimensions(1,4)+Dimensions(2,4));

for i = 1:4
    AreaFsum(i) = sum(AreaF(i,:));
end
% All of the view factors for both the 6x6 and 4x4 system check out!

%% Finding Modifying Matrices A(i,j)
%For an adiabatic surface -> Front, top, end 1 & end 2 (1, 2, 5, 6)
for i = 1:2
    for j = 1:6
        delta = 0;
        if i == j
            delta = 1;
        end
        a(i,j) = delta - F(i,j);
    end
end

for i = 5:6
    for j = 1:6
        delta = 0;
        if i == j
            delta = 1;
        end
        a(i,j) = delta - F(i,j);
    end
end

%For a gray or black surface -> Back & Floor (3, 4)
for i = 3:4
    for j = 1:6
        delta = 0;
        if i == j
            delta = 1;
        end
        a(i,j) = (delta - (1 - E(i)))*F(i,j)/E(i);
    end
end

%%Finding C
C = zeros(3,1);
for i = 1:6
    C(i) = Boltz*T(i)^4;
end

J = C\a;
T(1) = (J(1)/Boltz)^1/4;
T(2) = (J(2)/Boltz)^1/4;
T(5) = (J(5)/Boltz)^1/4;
T(6) = (J(6)/Boltz)^1/4;

J =
-4.06274139000839e-05   -2.01189679978546e-05   0   -4.06274139000839e-05   -1.01872814363003e-05   -1.01872814363003e-05
```

I've gone through and checked the values of the area and view factor matrices, and they seem to be working well. The view factors all add up to one for each face, and the messy areas aren't even being used until the next case so I doubt those are the culprit. The main suspect is the 'a' matrix, as it looks like this in the workspace:

```
1   -0.1669000000   -0.1669000000   -0.5090000000   -0.07870000000  -0.07870000000
-0.3338000000   1   -0.1653000000   -0.3338000000   -0.08370000000  -0.08370000000
-0.5007000000   -0.2479500000   0   -0.5007000000   -0.1255500000   -0.1255500000
0   0   0   0   0   0
-0.3148000000   -0.1674000000   -0.1674000000   -0.3148000000   1   -0.03620000000
-0.3148000000   -0.1674000000   -0.1674000000   -0.3148000000   -0.03620000000  1
```

The important thing to get from this is that, while the black surface (4) should be 0's for a majority, the point where it crosses at (4,4) shouldn't be. Similarly, the gray surface (3) is suspiciously 0 when it likely shouldn't be.

Comment: You’re posting a lot of code, without explaining what it is supposed to do, and expect us to find an error? Note that few people, if any, that will read your post will know the application field you’re working in. The few words you throw around don’t even give an indication of what this field is. Please read [ask] and especially [mre], then [edit] your post so people can understand what this is about.

Comment: ... and maybe include some images of the equations you are working with and trying to solve, so we can see how your code is related to the math.